# How can we Refresh Schema in the Mongo Db

Tags: mongodb

I have a client program through which I am connecting to mongoDb using JDBC connection. And I have created database and some collections. schema definition is not getting refreshed.

Comment: This is entirely the responsibility of that client program. Try restarting it, perhaps. Also, there's no schema in mongodb, so I'm not sure what _exactly_ are you trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB each document in the same collection can have absolute different structure (schema). So if you changed the document structure in the app it does not means that all documents automatically must become to the identical structure. If you want to update the structure (schema) for the existing documents, then you/your application should to do it manually (update each document).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to refresh the mongodb schema from my client application.
REFRESH SCHEMA  statement adds newly discovered objects to your relational view of native data type.